# Angular High Chart - Loading data from Observable

Tags: angular, highcharts

I am having trouble with getting my observable data into the High Chart. Angular 10. I can use it with other types of objects, like a material table. Thanks for any advice. This is what I'm currently doing:

I am looping a list of urls, (using an observable) Then capturing data from each one, each one being a temporary observable for just within the function. The site list and the site data is all assigned to a chartData array.

If I add to the array using hardcoded variables, only the hardcoded values show up on the chart. But if I print chartData to the console, all values show up.

What console looks like:
[console data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81r9M.png)

What the chart looks like:
[chart image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTPJn.png)

called from the component: This calls 'getSitesData', which is what loops each site, shown below.

```js
ngOnChanges(changes: { [propKey: string]: SimpleChange }) {

    this.chartData = [];
    
    this.chartData = this.reportingService.getSitesData(this.dateFrom,this.dateTo);
    
    //hardcoded values for example
    this.chartData.push({name: "Site -1", data: [331,4,62,7,34,8,23,8,3454,8,34,3,63,56]})
    this.chartData.push({name: "Site 0", data: [339.49,103.39,994,849.9,33,1991,3939.93,5699]})

    console.log("Card Component: this.ChartData " , this.chartData );

    this.refreshChart();
  
}
```

Called from reportingService:

```js
getSitesData(dateFrom: string, dateTo: string): any[] {    
    let series: any[];
    series = [];

    //get the sites
    this.getSites().subscribe(data => this.sites = data); 

    //loop the sites, add the series data to the second column of the array. 
    if (this.sites?.length) {
      for (let site of this.sites) {
          
          this.getSales(site, dateFrom, dateTo, this.groupBy).subscribe(
            data => {  this.salesPayments  = data 

                this.dataSeriesValues = []; 
                site.salesData = this.salesPayments;

                if (this.salesPayments?.length) {
                  for(var i = 0; i < this.salesPayments.length; i++)
                    (this.dataSeriesValues.push(this.salesPayments[i].amountPaid))
                }                        
                
                series.push({name: site.Name, data:  this.dataSeriesValues})  
                
            }
          )  
        }

        // this.chartData = series;
        return series;

      };
}
```

This is called in the component, within ngOnChanges after the getSitesData occurs:

```js
refreshChart() {

    this.chartOptions =  {
      chart: {
              type: 'area', 
              backgroundColor: null, 
              borderWidth: 0, 
              margin:[2,2,2,2], 
              height: 150
              },
        
         title: {
            text: "Sales By Day"
          },
        
        xAxis:{
        },

        yAxis: {          
            title:{
              text:""
            } 
        },

        series: this.chartData

      };
   
    HC_exporting(Highcharts);
    
    setTimeout(() => { 
      window.dispatchEvent(       
        new Event('resize')
      );
    }, 300);

};
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem starts within the Service. You are doing `this.getSites().subscribe(data => this.sites = data);` which is executed asynchronously. The following line `if (this.sites?.length) {...}` will always be empty as, since you are working with an observable, will be false (the result of that observable will arrive after the next line of code is executed).

Then you are again using `this.getSales(site, dateFrom, dateTo, this.groupBy)` which again returns an Observable. I suggest having a look on RX-JS Operators.

You need to refactor your code so it will return an Observable of any[] instead of any[]. (I won't go in why are you returning any[]).

```
getSitesData(dateFrom: string, dateTo: string): Observable<Array<any>> {
  return this.getSeries().pipe(
    concatMap( series => {
       return this.getSales(site, dateFrom, dateTo, this.groupBy)
    }),
    map( (resultArray) => { 
      return {} // you would have to construct your result based on the array recieved as parameter.
                // within the array you have the result of all api calls
    } ),
 
  }))
}
```

From there on, you can decide if you want to update some other state within the service by using tap() operator. As an example `this.dataSeriesValues = [];` (I don't know why but it doesn't matter). You could use after or before the map, the tap operator : `map((resultArray)=>{//whatever}), tap(resultArray=> // your logic)`

From the ngOnChanges() I would call the service, using `pipe(take(1)).subscribe(result => // this.data etc)` just to be sure I am not adding a memory leak (take(1) does unsubcribe)

Please have a look at RX-JS working with Observables.
P.S. You need to refactor your code :)

Comment: I did supply images of the console which shows that I'm receiving  this.getSites().subscribe(data => this.sites = data);

It is then able to load the salesData, and that was shown in the images I included. 

I can use this service fine with the HTML. In typescript, where I'm trying to build the Series data for the high charts, it's not working
 
This works fine:  <mat-card  *ngFor="let site of sites">

    {{ site.Name }} 

    <div *ngFor="let sales of site.salesData">
      <li> {{ sales.dateCompleted }} |  {{ sales.amountPaid }} </li>     
    </div>
      
  </mat-card>

Comment: Thanks, main points of your answer were essentially what I needed.

Comment: Glad I could help. Let me know if you have any other questions. Can you accept the answer or you need something else ?